# how to make screen only display white and black color in android except a child view

Tags: android

I want to make an activity layout only display black and white color except one child view. It must stay exact same color.

I am using the code below, but it effects the entire screen.

How can i prevent the view from this effect?

```
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    cm.setSaturation(1);
    Paint greyscalePaint = new Paint();
    greyscalePaint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
    rootView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, greyscalePaint);
```

Thanks

Comment: You have to manually set the same "setLayerType()" to all children but not your target parent(s).z it's the only solution.

Comment: Paint each child except the one you want to ignore like that?